# Cannot check NSDictionary object's value is null or not

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I try to check an objectforkey value of a NSDictionary. But I can't. 
In debug mode it says the value is this : 
    `LastOrderId = "<null>";` ;
This code or modified with isEqualtoString, doesn't work.

```
lastorderId=[theItem objectForKey:@"LastOrderId"];
if(lastorderId==nil)
        lastorderId=@"0";
```

When I try to make this code work :

```
NSInteger *newvalue = [[theItem valueForKey:@"LastOrderId"]integerValue] ;
```

,it gives this error:

```
-[NSNull integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3abeba70
```

How can I check that this is null or not? Thank you.

Comment: You are checking for `nil`, but your NSDictionary is giving you `NSNull`. Check for NSNull.

Comment: If you think about the error message a bit, and you read the documentation for `- [NSDictionary objectForKey:]`, then you can instantly come up with a solution. (I don't know how people learn programming nowadays, but don't you have a tiny bit of curiosity inside you? Along with some common sense and attention to detail? I remember having discovered pretty quickly the obvious fact that `<null>` isn't the same as `(null)`.)

Comment: @JAB What do you mean by "not valid syntax"? The one is the description of `NSNull`, the other is how often `nil` is formatted and printed.

Comment: I didn't know that <null> and (null) different. It 's my first time that I saw it. I just thought that it is a basic nil problem. Next time I'll research more deeply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Cocoa collections cannot store `nil`s, a special `NSNull` object is stored to denote `nil`s instead. These objects are not `nil`s, however, so the check that you tried does not work. You can do this instead:

```
lastorderId=[theItem objectForKey:@"LastOrderId"];
if(lastorderId==[NSNull null]) {
    lastorderId=@"0";
}
```